# Why does an empty Perl hash have one key?

Tags: perl, hash, size, key

The standard googleable answer to "How do I find out the size of a hash in Perl?" is "take the size of `keys(%hash)`":

```
my %h = {};
print scalar (keys (%h));
```

This prints '1'. I was expecting zero. On the other hand. Similarly,

```
my %h = {};
$h{"a"} = "b";
$h{"x"} = "y";
print scalar keys (%h);
print "\nKey: $_" for (keys %h);
```

Prints:

> 3
>
> Key: a
>
> Key: x
>
> Key: HASH(0x229e8)

Where has this extra value come from?

Comment: You should seriously consider enabling the `warnings` pragma. It would have catched this mistake.

Comment: Place these lines at the top of **ALL** you scripts:

    use strict;
    use warnings;

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has bit me before too.

```
my %h = ();
```

Note the use of `()` instead of `{}`.

Explanation: The value `{}` is a *reference* to a hash, rather than a hash itself. In Perl, a reference is a kind of scalar value, and the assignment to `%h` has special processing for assigning a single scalar value. It stringifies the scalar (giving you the string `HASH(0x229e8)` in your case), and associates that key with the value `undef`.

When using `()`, the assignment from list to hash creates key/value pairs from pairs in the list, and since `()` is empty, the hash `%h` becomes empty.

Comment: Exactly. And in the second example, %h={} will create an entry which maps `{} => UNDEF`.

Comment: This doesn't _explain_ the situation, though.

Comment: @Tomalak - sure it does. Read the comment above yours.

Comment: @Ingo: The comment implies the reasoning, but the answer most certainly does not explain it. I'm not saying that I have not figured out from the answer and comment what the situation is; I'm saying that the answer is incomplete.

Comment: In regards to being bitten, there is no reason to declare with `= ();` anyway. `my %h;` is less typing and less error prone.

Comment: Assigning a one-element list is in no way special; this claim makes the overall answer misleading.

Answer (score 24):

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -e'my %h = {}'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1.
```

[strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) are included with Perl for very good reasons. There is no reason not to use them.

Even better, add [diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) into the mix too:

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -Mdiagnostics -e'my %h = {}'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1 (#1)
    (W misc) You gave a single reference where Perl was expecting a list
    with an even number of elements (for assignment to a hash). This usually
    means that you used the anon hash constructor when you meant to use
    parens. In any case, a hash requires key/value pairs.

        %hash = { one => 1, two => 2, };    # WRONG
        %hash = [ qw/ an anon array / ];    # WRONG
        %hash = ( one => 1, two => 2, );    # right
        %hash = qw( one 1 two 2 );      # also fine
```

Comment: I always use strict, although I had no idea 'warnings' and 'diagnostics' were extra. Thanks!

Comment: 'diagnostics' is only for debugging though. Remove it when the program goes into production.

Comment: Use the `splain` command line utility to explain a perl error message.

Answer (score 7):

`{}` is a reference to an anonymous hash. So `my %h = {}` is equivalent to my `%h = ({} => undef)`.

Perl requires hash keys to be strings, so when you use a reference as a key, Perl uses the reference's string representation (`HASH(0x229e8)`).

Answer (score 6):

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = {};
warn Dumper \%h;
```

`%h` gets assigned with a hash reference as the key and `undef` as the value.

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x8683830)' => undef
        };
```

As [*rafl*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54157/rafl) suggested, the `warnings` pragma would have caught this. 
Look at [*Greg Hewgill*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633297/why-does-an-empty-perl-hash-have-one-key/5633309#5633309) for the corrected code.